# What is the meaning of * in the following example?

Tags: css

What is the meaning of `*` in this code ?

```css
.descendants * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="descendants" style="width:500px;">div (current element) 
  <p class="1">p (child)
    <span>span (grandchild)</span>     
  </p>
  <p class="2">p (child)
    <span>span (grandchild)</span>
  </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: "Open the following url" No. Please don't force readers to do this.

Answer (score 3):

`*` in CSS represents "any element".

In the above example, this will target any and all sub-elements of `.descendants`. Notice how the text in the first `div` is black, and the `p` and `span` content is grey and has a border? That is because the CSS selector is targeting those elements.

Comment: You could also say "any and all descendants of `.descendants`", but that would be better off as a setup for a tongue twister...

Comment: You're welcome @GopiNath. Welcome to StackOverflow. Consider [Accepting this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it solved your problem, to indicate to other users that this was the most helpful answer.